How to include/eval a command output in GNU Make?
Consider that a piece of GNU Makefile is generated by a command (probably because the list of variables to define is too complicated to achieve otherwise).
Script test.sh:
echo 'V1 = foo bar'
echo 'V2 = ab cd'

If I try this in the GNU Makefile:
$(eval $(shell ./test.sh))
$(info V1='$(V1)')
$(info V2='$(V2)')

I get this:
V1='foo bar V2 = ab cd'
V2=''

while I would like this:
V1='foo bar'
V2='ab cd'

I understand that $(shell) transforms new lines in spaces. I found similar, although not identical, questions online but answers were incorrect. For instance, using an explicit NL variable in the Makefile:
define NL


endef
$(eval $(shell ./test.sh))
$(info V1='$(V1)')
$(info V2='$(V2)')

and then creating a reference to $(NL) in the script:
echo 'V1 = foo bar$(NL)'
echo 'V2 = ab cd$(NL)'

I get this:
V1='foo bar
 V2 = ab cd
'
V2=''

The reference to $(NL) is replaced by one newline but that newline is swallowed into V1 instead of separating the definitions of variables.
I haven't found a way to use include directive from a command output (apart from creating a temporary file, which is quite ugly in terms of cleanup).

I think include of a temporary file might be the only viable option.  Yes, include files are specifically named, so they don't get removed automatically as intermediates, but I don't see why it's so hard to add one more to the list of things you $(RM) in your clean target.

You seem to be building a Rube Goldberg device.  If you want to configure details of your build programmatically, then the conventional way to do so is before you make.  In that approach, the configuration script writes makefile fragments to be included, or, often, creates the whole makefile.  Or if you just want to set some variables dynamically then write a script that wraps the make command and provides the wanted variables and values on the make command line.

To answer your question directly: there is no way that I can think of to do what you want without using a file on the filesystem.  The only way to retrieve the output of a shell command without writing it to the disk is via $(shell ...) and as you've discovered, the shell function can't be used to return multiple physical lines in a way that eval can interpret.  If you do want to use files on the filesystem, there are multiple options (depending a bit on which version of GNU Make you're using).

I appreciate positive contributions, even imperfect, because the author tries something. People who assert that something is impossible apparently assume that they have universal knowledge of what can possibly be done. People who assert that we should not do something apparently assume that they have universal wisdom of what is good or not, what people should or shouldn't do, that no other use case can exist. And by the way, it's possible, I just found the solution by myself (see answer).

This is an addendum to Thierry's self-answer to show how the ugliness can be isolated in a single function, which I'll call shell-lines, with no need to modify the shell script.  We can pipe the script's output through sed to replace newline with a marker of our choice and subst it back to newline:
define NL


endef

EOL = --EOL--
shell-lines = $(subst $(EOL),$(NL),$(shell ( $1 ) | sed 's/$$/$(EOL)/'))

Then we simply call this function - here, I'll inline a couple of commands rather than execute an external script:
$(eval $(call shell-lines, echo 'V1 = foo bar'; echo 'V2 = ab cd'))

Some notes:

The shell command is run in a subshell, so that the whole output is piped through sed even if we supply multiple commands connected with ;, || or &&.
We needed to write $$ for sed to see $ matching end of line.
We can redefine EOL between invocations - it should be something guaranteed not to occur naturally in output.


Full makefile (for testing):
define NL


endef

EOL = --EOL--
shell-lines = $(subst $(EOL),$(NL),$(shell ( $1 ) | sed 's/$$/$(EOL)/'))

$(eval $(call shell-lines, printf '%s = %s\n' V1 'foo bar' V2 'ab cd'))

$(info V1='$(V1)')
$(info V2='$(V2)')

all:
    @:


After multiple retries, I finally found a solution. The key is the order of substitutions in Makefile (which is not quite well documented), functions first, then variables.
When the script echoes 'V1 = foo bar$(NL)', the new line are substituted at the end of the process, just before evaluating the expression. At that time, the expression was already analyzed as one single line, as one single variable definition.
However, if we use some end-of-line marker instead, e.g. '=EOL=', and then substitute it with $(NL) in the $(eval) expression in the makefile, it works. The $(subst) function is evaluated first, and the expression is later evaluated as multiple lines.
Script:
EOL='=EOL='
echo 'V1 = ab cd'$EOL
echo 'V2 = ef gh'$EOL

Makefile:
$(eval $(subst =EOL=,$(NL),$(shell ./test.sh)))
$(info V1='$(V1)')
$(info V2='$(V2)')

Output:
$ make 
V1='ab cd'
V2='ef gh'

Not quite pretty but done only once in the makefile.

That's ugly but effective!  You can avoid changes to the script, and localise the ugliness in a single Make function like this: shell-lines = $(subst ==EOL,$(NL),$(shell ($1) | sed 's/$$/==EOL/'))  Then the usage is only slightly different to your original: $(eval $(call shell-lines, ./test.sh))

@TobySpeight, nice improvement indeed, no dirty EOL marker in the shell script, much cleaner, much better. Thank you !

@TobySpeight just one typo : $(shell ($1) should be $(shell $(1)

No, that's not a typo - if we have multiple commands connected with ; or &&, then we want their entire output to be filtered through sed.  So that's why I have a subshell there.

OK, understood. However, I would have written ($(1)) in that case because the rule of single-character variable name without parentheses is confusing and I never use it. That's why I thought there was a character inversion.
